# ChromeDriver and OperaDriver fail when running tests on Visual Studio Team Services (VS Online)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, msbuild, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

We're using `MSTest` with Team Services (Visual Studio Online) builds to run our Selenium Tests.
`FirefoxDriver` and `InternetExplorerDriver` are running correctly, however `ChromeDriver` and `OperaDriver` are failing everytime, without even being able to open the browser.
They fail everytime with the following stacktrace:

```
Initialization method WebUnitTests.Tests.DatacenterTests.TestInitialize threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:1410/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
at WebUnitTests.Framework.Utilities.Driver.StartBrowser(BrowserTypes browserType, Int32 defaultTimeOut) in C:\agent2\_work\1\s\WebUnitTests\Framework\Utilities\Driver.cs:line 37
at WebUnitTests.Framework.Utilities.BaseTests.InitializeBrowser(TestContext testContext) in C:\agent2\_work\1\s\WebUnitTests\Framework\Utilities\BaseTests.cs:line 328
at WebUnitTests.Framework.Utilities.BaseTests.TestInitialize() in C:\agent2\_work\1\s\WebUnitTests\Framework\Utilities\BaseTests.cs:line 147
```

What I'm using to start the driver:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
var chromeBrowser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

One very important thing to mention is that if I'm running the tests on my local machine everything works fine, the issue is only when they're run in CI.

Any ideas in what I could try to find the root problem? Any workarounds to solve this?

Comment: Did you configure the build/test agent to run in interactive mode? And will it run successfully if you run the test on the build/test agent manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems the issue is a bit more complex, but I'm posting this in case someone is in the same situation.

Basically the Test Agent was installed as a service, and every process launched from a Windows (NT) Service runs on Session 0, invisible to a logged on user.

Chrome is trying to move away from Session 0 and you can find further references of this here (comment 21 in the link below, but actually the whole thread is a good read in respect to this subject): 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396#c21

Now, to fix this, there are several options available:
Download a Canary build from [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) but this is not recommended as this is only a temporary fix. Chrome devs are saying that in the near future Session 0 will no longer be available with Chrome (and ChromeDriver).

The best solution is to have MS Test Agent installed as a process so that all applications are visible to the logged in user. More details can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx

Another option for this is to have the settings below added as Chrome arguments, however I didn't test with those using the Test Agent as a Windows Service, so I don't know if it's working or not, but I can confirm that it's working with the Test Agent as a process.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```